# Mockito | JUnit | Avro: Mocking a void method does not work

Tags: java, serialization, junit, mockito, avro

I wrote a method for avro serialization, which I want to test.

**Method**

```
@SneakyThrows
@Override
public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        writeSerializedAvro(stream, data, data.getSchema());
        return stream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AvroSerializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void writeSerializedAvro(ByteArrayOutputStream stream, T data, Schema schema) throws IOException {
    binaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(stream, binaryEncoder);
    DatumWriter<T> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    datumWriter.write(data, binaryEncoder);
    binaryEncoder.flush();
}
```

`datumWriter.write` or `binaryEncoder.flush()` can throw `IOException`.

In the test, I want to see if `IOException` is thrown, my method catchers it and wraps it in `AvroSerializationException` (a class written by me).

**Unit Test**

```
    @Test(expected = AvroSerializationException.class)
public void testSerializeException() throws IOException {
    // Given 
// need to mock here

    // When
    serializer.serialize("", avroObject);
}
```

I have tried mocking `GenericDatumWriter`, `BufferedBinaryEncoder` and `EncoderFactory` with `doThrow().when()` methods but nothing worked for me.

```
BufferedBinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = Mockito.mock(BufferedBinaryEncoder.class);
Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(binaryEncoder).flush();
```

And

```
    GenericDatumWriter datumWriter = Mockito.mock(GenericDatumWriter.class);
    Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(datumWriter).write(any(), any());
```

But again, the question comes back to, how am I supposed to pass these objects to my serializer, keeping the best practices in mind?

Comment: Please see [mcve]. "I have tried" ... but where is your code doing that?! The whole point of mocking is: you need to know what you are doing. You didnt tell us what you did do exactly, so what exactly do you expect that we tell you?

Comment: Beyond that, I sense that the real answer is: you should step back and really research how to use such mocking frameworks. You probably heard "okay, i can mock things", but it seems nobody told you yet: the mocked objects *somehow* need to be passed to your production code, so that they are actually invoked. In other words: a mocking framework alone is pointless. You have to learn how to write testable code, so that you can easily *make use* of such frameworks, in order to get to decent production and test code.

Comment: @GhostCat Agree with your point. I've been used to patching classes while unit testing in Python, something which I can't do in Java (or can I?) ... So what do you suggest? Having a setter for `DatumWriter` looks like bad code to me.

Comment: @GhostCat added what I've tried.

Comment: There are various ways to get there. One way: have a (non public) constructor that takes that object as parameter (unless that object is already set as some ctor parameter). Alternatively, there is the InjectMocks annotation. That does some magic, but the problem is that you dont get any errors when it fails to inject. Coming back to my point: this is not something that you can pick up based on 5 minutes of feedback stackoverflow. If you want to do real work with java and mockito, you have to bite the bullet and sit down for a day or two and learn how to properly do things.

Comment: The answer is correct then - you created a mock. But a mock doesnt magically by itself find its way into your production code. Any good mockito tutorial will explain that to you ...

Comment: After careful analysis, I thought, given that `writeSerializedAvro` is a private methiod, I should be sending an input to the `serialize` method to which `writeSerializedAvro` method raises an `IOException`, but how do I make such an input?

Comment: I dont get your question. And honestly, this getting a bit out of hand. There is a wide variety of options how to approach this topic. But in order to have a meaningful discussion, we would have to sit down and understand your requirements, your current code base ... and so on. To then work together on options, and what could be done, and try things. That is not what this community is about. You asked "what is missing", and the answer is: you *somehow* have to get your mocks to your production objects. How to do that exactly ... depends on many things.

Comment: So please consider to follow my initial advice: step back, and accept that you need to **learn** these things. There are no detours. If you want to get to a solution that works for you, you have to understand what you are doing. So: read a good tutorial. Work through the whole thing. Start adapting your code. And then, when you have done all that, and you are still stuck ... then write a new question, with a real [mcve] and ask about that. But please stop playing "more questions in comments" ping pong.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to mock the object using Mockito and use it in your class and then the exception will be thrown, like below:

Your code:

```
private DatumWriter<T> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);

@SneakyThrows
@Override
public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        writeSerializedAvro(stream, data, data.getSchema());
        return stream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AvroSerializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void writeSerializedAvro(ByteArrayOutputStream stream, T data, Schema schema) throws IOException {
    binaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(stream, binaryEncoder);
    datumWriter.write(data, binaryEncoder);
    binaryEncoder.flush();
}

public void setDatumWriter (DatumWriter datumWriter){
   this.datumWriter=datumWriter;
}
```

Your test code:

```
@Test(expected = AvroSerializationException.class)
public void testSerializeException() throws IOException {
    // Given 
    DatumWriter<YourClass> datumWriter = Mockito.mock(DatumWriter<YourClass>.class);
    when(datumWriter.write(anyObject(), anyObject())).thenThrow(IOException.class);
    
    serializer.setDatumWriter(datumWriter);  
   
    serializer.serialize("", avroObject);
}
```

Comment: You should emphasize that this is only *one* suggestion how to make things testable. Making a **setter** just for testing is a big code smell.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately, we can't use Mockito without injecting the mocked object. This is the bad things about frameworks, frameworks help you achieve advanced features, on the other hand, you need to couple your code with it.

Comment: Not exactly true. Mockito has the InjectMocks annotation, which uses reflection to "get" objects into your production object under test. But that annotation has some aspects that prevent me from using it , too

Comment: What about using a constructor instead?

Comment: Sure, we normally do "constructor telescoping" for example. But depending how good people are about keeping classes small ... that might lead to nasty lengthy constructors that take a lot of objects. But yes, I prefer that over the inject annotation.